# Truncate a log file by datetime using Powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell

We have a simple log file. It gets too big or the entries irrelevant as they age. Entries have a datetime prefix similar to this:

> 01/22/15 01:54:17 -I- Start processing stuff

Occasionally the log entries span multiple lines like this:

```
01/23/15 01:18:00 -E- java.io.IOException: (101) Error between keyboard and chair
     at this.mod.no.worky(what_were_you_thinking:duh)
```

We simply want to remove the (entire) entries before some cutoff date, call it 30 days for example.

Solutions that truncate to a fixed number of lines or bytes don't work in this case.

Most recent attempt with dreadful performance:

```
$cutDatePtrn = "^" + (get-date).AddDays(-30).tostring("MM/dd/yy ")
$newStartLine = (select-string -Path $logFile -Pattern $cutDatePtrn -Quiet -List).LineNumber
$tmp = $logFile + '.tmp'
get-content $logFile | select -skip $newStartLine | out-file $tmp
```

Comment: Oh right. I've been wasting time with StreamReader/StreamWriter... Generally revolving around finding the first line that starts after the cutoff date and writing out the rest of the file.

Comment: you may try to base your solution on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4192419/1123692

Comment: Thanks @wmz. But the post you are referencing advocates not using PowerShell for this (I agree) and using StreamReader if one insists on using Powershell. My project is looking specifically for a Powershell implementation that is faster than available using streamreader/streamwriter.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you [that you want to use cmdlets only] - but the question I linked does include some advice on speeding up get-content (namely, do not assign it to variable and use high `-ReadCount`) - but if it'd be me I'd cheat and use `Logparser` for the task (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd919274.aspx - which technically, you could call 'powershell implementation' as it exposes com interface so you can reference it from PS with `new-object -com`)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the PowerShell solution using Streams. Takes ~60 seconds to process 1GB file on my laptop (*i3 2.5GHz, 4GB RAM, 5400RPM HDD)*. It still three time slower than [LogParser](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659), though:

```
LOGPARSER "Select Text from C:\Path\To\log.file where Text like '01/22/15%'" -i:TEXTLINE -q:Off
```

```powershell
$LogFolder = 'c:\Path\To\Log\Folder'
$Filter = '*.log'
$Postfix = '.tmp'
$cutDatePtrn = '^' + (Get-Date).AddDays(-30).ToString('MM/dd/yy')

# Iterate over each log file in the $LogFolder
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $LogFolder -Filter $Filter |
    ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "Current file: $($_.FullName)"
        $InFile = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.StreamReader -ArgumentList $_.FullName

        Write-Host 'Processing file...'

        $WriteFile = $false
        while(($line = $InFile.ReadLine()) -ne $null)
        {
            if((-not $WriteFile) -and ($line -notmatch $cutDatePtrn))
            {
                continue
            }
            elseif((-not $WriteFile) -and ($line -match $cutDatePtrn))
            {
                Write-Host 'Found match:'
                Write-Host $line

                $WriteFile = $true
                $TmpFile = $_.FullName + $Postfix

                Write-Host "Creating new temporary file: $TmpFile"
                $OutFile = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.StreamWriter -ArgumentList $TmpFile, $false
            }

            $OutFile.WriteLine($line)
        }

        Write-Host 'Done processing, cleaning up...'
        if($OutFile)
        {

            $OutFile.Flush()
            $OutFile.Close()
            $OutFile.Dispose()
        }

        $InFile.Close()
        $InFile.Dispose()

        if(Test-Path $TmpFile -PathType Leaf)
        {
            Write-Host "Deleting original file: $($_.FullName)"
            Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -Force

            Write-Host "Renaming temporary file: $TmpFile -> $($_.FullName)"
            Rename-Item -Path $TmpFile -NewName $_.FullName -Force
        }

        Write-Host "Finished processing file: $($_.FullName)"
        }
```

Comment: Ah, nice effort. Let me look this over and post an update. Thanks beatcracker.